# How to find which indexes and constraints contain a specific column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am planing a database change and I have a list of columns included in process. Can I list all indexes in which is a specific column included?

**Edit**

So far I have (combined from answers):

```
declare @TableName nvarchar(128), @FieldName nvarchar(128)
select  @TableName= N'<<Table Name>>', @FieldName =N'<<Field Name>>'
(SELECT distinct systab.name AS TABLE_NAME,sysind.name AS INDEX_NAME, 'index' 
FROM sys.indexes sysind 
INNER JOIN sys.index_columns sysind_col 
    ON  sysind.object_id = sysind_col.object_id and sysind.index_id = sysind_col.index_id 
INNER JOIN sys.columns sys_col 
    ON sysind_col.object_id = sys_col.object_id and sysind_col.column_id = sys_col.column_id 
INNER JOIN sys.tables systab
    ON sysind.object_id = systab.object_id

WHERE systab.is_ms_shipped = 0 and sysind.is_primary_key=0 and sys_col.name  =@FieldName and systab.name=@TableName

union
select t.name TABLE_NAME,o.name, 'Default' OBJ_TYPE
 from sys.objects o 
inner join sys.columns c on o.object_id  = c.default_object_id
inner join sys.objects t on c.object_id  = t.object_id 
where o.type  in ('D') and c.name  =@FieldName and t.name=@TableName
union

SELECT u.TABLE_NAME,u.CONSTRAINT_NAME,  'Constraint' OBJ_TYPE  
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE u 

where u.COLUMN_NAME  = @FieldName and u.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
) order by 1
```

But I am not too happy with combining of `sys.` and 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.' **Can it be avoided?**

Answer (score 4):

```
---Using sp_helpindex and your TableName
exec sp_helpindex YourTableName

---Using sys.tables with your TableName and ColumnName
select distinct c.name, i.name, i.type_desc,...
from sys.indexes i
        join sys.index_columns ic on i.index_id = ic.index_id 
        join sys.columns c on ic.column_id = c.column_id
where i.object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'YourTableName') and c.name = 'YourColumnName'
```

**EDIT:** As per comment, you can also join object_Ids without using `distinct`

```
select c.name, i.name, i.type_desc
from sys.indexes i
        join sys.index_columns ic on i.index_id = ic.index_id and i.object_id = ic.object_id
        join sys.columns c on ic.column_id = c.column_id and ic.object_id = c.object_id
where i.object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'YourTableName') and c.name = 'YourColumnName'
```

Comment: Should not be object_id included also in joins? It seems to return too much rows.

Comment: I have updated with object_id join, that obviously better than using `Distinct`.

Answer (score 3):

SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE

USE TABLE_NAME IN WHERE if you what to know the constraint on a table.

and use column_name if you know the column name.

Comment: Also Use Database name if like <databasename>.information_schema.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE if you are using this outside the database

Comment: Thanks for constraints, but I also need indexes.

Answer (score 2):

To get information regarding all indexes in which is a specific column is included following two catalog views can be used:

```
sys.indexes , sys.index_columns
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
     sysind.name AS INDEX_NAME
    ,sysind.index_id AS  INDEX_ID
    ,sys_col.name AS COLUMN_NAME
    ,systab.name AS TABLE_NAME
FROM sys.indexes sysind 
INNER JOIN sys.index_columns sysind_col 
    ON  sysind.object_id = sysind_col.object_id and sysind.index_id = sysind_col.index_id 
INNER JOIN sys.columns sys_col 
    ON sysind_col.object_id = sys_col.object_id and sysind_col.column_id = sys_col.column_id 
INNER JOIN sys.tables systab
    ON sysind.object_id = systab.object_id 
WHERE (1=1) 
      AND systab.is_ms_shipped = 0 
      AND sys_col.name  IN(specific column list for which indexes are to be queried)
ORDER BY 
    systab.name,sys_col.name, sysind.name,sysind.index_id
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the sys schema on your database then you can query `sys.indexes` to get the index ID and use that with the function `index_col` to get the columns. The final parameter for `index_col` is the index of the column within the index (i.e. if there are 3 columns in the index you would have to call `index_col` 3 times with 1, 2, 3 in the last parameter)

```
select index_id from sys.indexes
 where object_id = object_id(@objectname)

select index_col(@objectname, @indexid, 1)
```

This should give you constraints as well as they are just special indexes.

Comment: I know the column name and the table name and I am looking for an index.